# Third party session state provider for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Am looking for a third party tool/provider of session state/caching in an ASP.NET context.

Comment: What should it do  compared to the normal provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TroubleshootingExpiredASPNETSessionStateAndYourOptions.aspx) (at the end of the post there's a list of third party providers like `NCache`, `ScaleOut` and `Memcached`).

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into Windows AppFabric.